# Why is the Latin script in LM Math derived from Euler rather than cmsy?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, unicode-math, latin-modern

Recently, I noticed that the script alphabet in the OpenType version of Latin Modern Math (henceforth referred to as LM Math) does not match the one of Computer Modern (also known as `\mathcal`).  The Latin script which is available in LM Math seems to be a slanted variant of the Euler script font.  I wonder why that design decision was made in that way.

From the [website](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math):

> The Latin Modern Math (LM Math) font completes the modernization of the Computer Modern family of typefaces designed and programmed by Donald E. Knuth.
>
> [...]
>
> LM and LM Math taken together may now be regarded as a full descendant of Computer Modern.

This confuses me even more.  LM Math is advertised as the successor of Computer Modern but breaks with the script font.

**Why did the font developers choose Euler over Computer Modern for the Latin script?**

---

Below you can find some examples to compare for yourself.

#### Computer Modern

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Euler

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### LM Math

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's only one of Latin Modern's script fonts.

Comment: It isn't what's in the traditional fonts. But I don't know how the script font maps onto the unicode stuff.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was a design choice. In TUGboat, Volume 37 (2016), No. 3, https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents37-3.html, in the article ["GUST e-foundry font projects"](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-3/tb117jackowski.pdf), pages 317-336, the authors of the font wrote on page 326:

> We have to confess, however, that we were not especially delighted
>   with the Computer Modern calligraphic script. More pleasingly designed,
>   to our eyes, are the calligraphic letters of the renowned Euler
>   family. Therefore, we decided to transfer the glyphs from the Euler
>   fonts (slanting them slightly) to the LM Math font.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the article? (possibly not accessible to the public yet)

Comment: @HenriMenke -- link added, and it *is* (somewhat to my surprise) already open to all.

Answer (score 4):

> ***Conjecture:*** Neither Computer Modern Symbol's script nor its successor,
>   Latin Modern Symbol's script, provide the symbols the MATH table
>   requires. The OMS encoding does not provide lower-case script. Euler
>   does. Hence, the script symbols are taken from Euler rather than Latin
>   Modern Symbol.

The font you show as Latin Modern script is only one of Latin Modern's. In particular, it is not what is used for `\mathcal` with traditional fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

The same result can be obtained by loading `lmodern` or, with no packages, by using

```
\fontencoding{OMS}\fontfamily{lmsy}\selectfont
```

[image: Latin Modern script]

In order to qualify as a maths opentype font, Latin Modern Math has to provide a complete MATH table and this requires a number of script fonts and maths alphabets - more than those provided by Computer Modern or the type1 version of Latin Modern derived from it.

For this reason, the developers of Latin Modern Math also based some elements of this font on fonts other than Computer Modern. This includes the calligraphic and fraktur fonts which are, as you say, based on Euler. (This is explained in the [README](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/readme-latin-modern-math.txt/view).) I would have guessed from the README that the font derived from Computer Modern Symbol, on which Latin Modern Symbol is based, would be available in Latin Modern Math, but that it is expected to be accessed as `\mathscr`.

> The math OTF fonts should contain a special table, MATH, described in
>   the  confidential Microsoft document "The MATH table and OpenType
>   Features  for Math Processing". Moreover, they should contain a broad
>   collection of special characters (see "Draft Unicode Technical Report
>
> ## 25. UNICODE SUPPORT FOR MATHEMATICS" by Barbara Beeton, Asmus Freytag, and Murray Sargent III). In particular, math OTF fonts are
>
> expected to contain the following scripts: a basic serif script
>   (regular, bold,  italic and bold italic), a calligraphic script
>   (regular and bold),  a double-struck script, a fraktur script (regular
>   and bold), a sans-serif  script (regular, bold, oblique and bold
>   oblique), and a monospaced script.
>
> The basic script is, obviously, Latin Modern. Some scripts, however,
>   are borrowed from other fonts (the current selection, however, may be
>   subject to change), belonging, however, to the "TeX circle":
>
> - the calligraphic and fraktur alphabets are excerpted from the
>     renowned
>     Euler family (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMS_Euler);
> - the double struck script is excerpted from Alan Jeffrey's bbold
>     font
>     (http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/bbold/bbold.pdf)
> - the sans serif and monospaced alphabets are excerpted from 
>     the Latin Modern Sans and Latin Modern Mono fonts
>     (http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern);
>     sans serif bold Greek symbols (required by the already mentioned
>     "Unicode Technical Report #25") were prepared using D.E. Knuth's
>     font sources with some manual tuning

However, `unicode-math` uses the same fonts for normal and bold `\mathscr` as it does for `\mathcal`. Looking at the font in FontForge, it contains multiple copies of the Euler-based script, but no copy of the Latin Modern Symbol script. However, I guess by the 'serif script', they just been the roman.

One reason to use Euler rather than Latin Modern Symbol is that the latter script only includes upper case, but the MATH table requires both. Hence, there is no model in Computer Modern or Latin Modern Symbol for a lower-case script alphabet. It seems a reasonable guess that this motivated the decision to substitute Euler. Euler provided what Knuth's OMS encoding did not: lower-case letters.

Comment: I'm referring to the OpenType variant of Latin Modern Math in my question.  I will make it more clear.

Comment: @HenriMenke I know. But you asked about the designers of the fonts. I'm pointing out that there is a Latin Modern script based on the Computer Modern calligraphic one.

Comment: ... which is not available in the OpenType version.

Comment: @HenriMenke I'm not so sure. Have you checked the font itself? You're sure this is not a `unicode-math` bug? The `\mathcal` is giving the *expected* behaviour i.e. an Euler-like script, which is by design. But that doesn't necessarily mean the script from `lmsy` is not there.

Comment: I inspected the font with FontForge and couldn't find glyphs from `lmsy`.  Also the question is *why* the script is derived from Euler rather than `lmsy`.

Comment: @HenriMenke I did, too. I updated above. I think the simple answer is that Euler had what Knuth didn't provide: lower-case script letters. The MATH table needs these, but the OMS encoding doesn't include them.

Comment: @HenriMenke barbara will know for sure, of course.

Comment: @cfr Henri is quite right. The open type font "Latin Modern Math" has taken some glyphs from other fonts. Beside others "the calligraphic and fraktur alphabets are excerpted from the renowned  Euler family", see the readme on CTAN https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm-math?lang=en. (I don't know why, perhaps they simply prefered the look, or the sources were better).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I quoted that above in my answer. I would assume they needed a script with lower-case, as I say. However, it seems from your answer they just preferred them.