# How can I get a less-curly \mathcal{T} with xelatex?

Tags: pandoc, mathcal

I'm compiling the following document with pandoc:

```
$\mathcal{T}$
```

using this command line:

```
pandoc -s --from markdown --to latex -o foo.pdf <(echo 'foo: $\mathcal{T}$')
```

If I use xelatex (`--pdf-engine xelatex`), the result looks like this:

[image: a very curly letter T]

but with pdflatex (the default, or `--pdf-engine pdflatex`), it looks like this:

[image: a slightly less curly letter T]

I'd like to be using xelatex if I can, but I prefer the result from pdflatex here – what's causing the difference, and is there a way to make xelatex output mathcal letters that are more like those produced by pdflatex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you want to stick with the classical Computer Modern `\mathcal` while using XeLaTeX, you can try `\let\mathcal\relax\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalfa}`.

Comment: Your issue would appear to be related more to pandoc than to xelatex. For sure, the simple program `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} $\mathcal{T}$ \end{document}` produces the exact same output under pdflatex, xelatex, and lualatex, *viz.*, the non-curly variety of the caligraphic letter.

Comment: xelatex uses unicode-math and so latin modern math. It is a design decision of the  font designer to make the mathcal more curly. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385489/why-is-the-latin-script-in-lm-math-derived-from-euler-rather-than-cmsy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer added per OP’s request.

---

The more curly “T” is from the OpenType version of Latin Modern: [Latin Modern Math (OTF), version 1.959](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html). As @UlrikeFischer explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385528/164314), this was a design choice.

Assuming the following is what happened with you current situation:

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{T}$ % <- This produces the more curly calligraphic script
\end{document}
```

To get the classical Computer Modern calligraphic script back, without the need to search the font name and to learn about font declaration, you may consider using the [`mathalfa`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalfa) package:

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\let\mathcal\relax % <- Just in case (This is usually unnecessary).
\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{T}$ % <- Classical Computer Modern calligraphic script
\end{document}
```