# Hat on \mathcal{J} and \mathcal{K} "off-center" due to \DeclareMathAlphabet

Tags: unicode-math, mathcal, newcomputermodern

I am using NCM (NewComputerModern) as my main font.
Because I do not like the `\mathcal{…}` provided by `unicode-math` in the Euler font instead of the `Latin Modern` oder `Computer Modern` style.

I think that I am switching to `Computer Modern Symbol` (`cmsy`) with

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
```

I got the cmd from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307745/xelatex-latin-modern-mathbb-and-mathcal).

This causes the `\hat{…}` cmd to be slightly off-center if you compare it without `unicode-math` in `Latin Modern Math`.

The first is with the Euler Font. I think the spacing of the `mathcal` letters is being used to set the `hat` symbol which causes it to be slightly off-center (I could be wrong though).

[image]

How do I get the "correct" position?

This is how it should look like (although the hat symbol has a weird width in this one):

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{NewCM10-Book.otf}
\setmathfont[CharacterVariant=1]{NewCMMath-Book.otf}
\setmathfont[range={scr,bfscr}]{XITS Math}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
    $\hat{\mathcal{J}} \hat{\mathcal{K}} $
\end{document}
```

Similar posts:
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385489/why-is-the-latin-script-in-lm-math-derived-from-euler-rather-than-cmsy) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307745/xelatex-latin-modern-mathbb-and-mathcal)

Comment: As always please post a full bit minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Then it is easier to know what you are doing and what setup your a re working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I may have found a "better" solution than what I was using before.

I am assuming (but really just guessing) that with `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}`
internally the font-shape and width of the characters by the other font was used which caused the misaligned `\hat{…}` for `\mathcal{J}` and `\mathcal{K}`.

After testing and trying I came to look up what `cmsy` is actually called
as a file that is installed.

It turns out that the file is called `cmsy10` (actually ranging from 5 to 10; so `cmsy5`, `cmsy6`, …).

So now to the fixed MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[CharacterVariant=1]{NewCMMath-Book.otf}
\setmathfont[range={scr,bfscr}]{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={cal}]{cmsy10} % the FIXED implementation of the CM Calligraphic Font
\setmathfont[StylisticSet=1,range={bfcal}]{XITS Math} % not necessary but allows also for bfcal

\begin{document}
    $\hat{\mathcal{J}} \hat{\mathcal{K}} $
    \\[2ex]
    $\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
    \\[2ex]
    $\mathbfcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
    \\[2ex]
    $\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
    \\[2ex]
    $\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
    \\[2ex]
    $\mathbb{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
\end{document}
```

[image]